# Cython and deepcopy() woes with referenced methods/functions. Any alternative ideas?

Tags: python, cython, typeerror

I've been playing with Cython recently for the speed ups, but my project inherits a module that has a `copy()` method which uses `deepcopy()`. I tried implementing the `deepcopy()` within an overrided version of `copy()`, and I thought I had it working, but it doesn't appear to be anymore.

```
TypeError: object.__new__(cython_binding_builtin_function_or_method) is not safe,
   use cython_binding_builtin_function_or_method.__new__()
```

This is occuring in python/lib/copy_reg.py here:

```
return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
```

I'm on Python 2.7 here. Is it possible that a newer version of Python returns from `deepcopy()` in a "safe" way? I'm also on the latest version of Cython, 0.15.1.

### Update3

*Note that I've removed the previous updates to keep this as simple as possible.*

Ok! I think I found the incompatibility but I don't really know what to do about it.

```
class CythonClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._handle = self._handles.get("handle_method")

    def call_handle(self):
        self._handle(self)

    def handle_method(self):
        print "I'm a little handle!"

    handles = {"handle_method", handle_method}
```

Then in my main app:

```
from cython1 import CythonClass
from copy import deepcopy

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gc1 = CythonClass()
    gc1.call_handle()
    gc2 = deepcopy(gc1)
```

I get:

```
I'm a little handle!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cythontest.py", line 8, in <module>
    gc2 = deepcopy(gc1)
  File "C:\python26\lib\copy.py", line 162, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\python26\lib\copy.py", line 292, in _deepcopy_inst
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\python26\lib\copy.py", line 162, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\python26\lib\copy.py", line 255, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\python26\lib\copy.py", line 189, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "C:\python26\lib\copy.py", line 323, in _reconstruct
    y = callable(*args)
  File "C:\python26\lib\copy_reg.py", line 93, in __newobj__
    return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: object.__new__(cython_binding_builtin_function_or_method) is not safe, use cython_binding_builtin_function_or_method.__new__()
```

The key is the function/handle reference:

```
handles = {"handle_method", handle_method}
```

If I don't include the method/function reference, Cython will not blow up during deepcopy. If I include one, it doesn't like how deepcopy/copy_reg copies the reference over.

Any ideas besides not using method/function references? I have a bit of untangling to do if that the simple answer. (which I'm already working on as I finish typing this)

Thanks!

Comment: If you moved your solution to an answer, and accepted it, it could help others who search for questions that have been answered.

Comment: Thanks Clare. I couldn't find the Answer button (!), the page is a bit busy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah, finally found the "Answer your own question" button.

I'm probably being impatient, but since nobody has replied yet (I mean who's using Cython and answering questions on a Thursday afternoon), I thought I would close this one off.

1) Cython doesn't like deepcopy on Classes which have function/method referenced variables. Those variable copies will fail. From what I can tell, there's no working around it, you just have to come up with an new design that doesn't require them. I ended up doing so with the same code above, and in my project.

2) Cython doesn't handle the property decorators at all. You can't `@property` and `@<property name>.setter`. Properties need to be set the old fashion way. e.g. `<property name> = property(get_property, set_property)`.

3) An inherited non-Cython class's methods "might" not be accessible. I know this vague. I can't completely explain it. All I'll say is I was inheriting `NetworkX.DiGraph`, and `number_of_nodes()` was no accessible after Cython, when it was straight Python. I had to create a reference to the method and use it. e.g. `number_of_verts = NetworkX.DiGraph.number_of_nodes`.

Answer (score 9):

found this:

*"Does deepcopy work properly with Cython?"*

*No. In this case (you are using extension types, i.e cdef classes) you
have to implement the pickle protocol for your class
http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-extension-types*

from here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/p2mzJrnOH4Q

"implementing the pickle protocol" in the linked article is actually simple, and solved my problems trivially (although I am doing things slightly differently - my class is a `cdef class`, and I have a pointer to a CPP object stored there which cannot be trivially duplicated - I don't know if this will solve the python-inheritance problem above, but it is certainly worth a try.)

Anyway, implementing the pickle protocol is trivial (the example below is using "C++ cython", which has a double meaning for the `del` keyword, [among other things](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html).):

```
cdef class PyObject(object):
    cdef CppObject* cpp
    cdef object arg1
    cdef object arg2

    def __cinit__(self, arg1=[], arg2=False):
        # C++ constructor using python values, store result in self.cpp.

        # new code: cache the python arguments that were used.
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def __init__(self, arg1=[], arg2=False):
        # logic for validating arguments.
        pass

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if not self.cpp == NULL:
            del self.cpp

    def __reduce__(self):
        # a tuple as specified in the pickle docs - (class_or_constructor, 
        # (tuple, of, args, to, constructor))
        return (self.__class__, (self.arg1, self.arg2))
```

When I try this, I can call `copy.deepcopy()` on a dict containing an instance of my Cython extension type, and get a new dictionary containing a new instance (with a different memory address when printed to terminal.) Previously the same code caused a segfault.

Comment: could you provide an example of how this class can be the substitution for `copy` method in python, especially it has been used to call another class?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "call another class"? do you mean you have a reference to the object to be copied on another instance object? To clarify, this class is not a substitution for `copy.deepcopy`, the idea (in case this isn't clear) is to use `copy.deepcopy` *on* an instance of this type of class, to copy it. The original problem was that this doesn't normally work on cython classes, but it does on this cython class.

Comment: I mean something like this `class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, m = 0.3, l = 0.7):

        self.m = m
        self.l = l
    def __copy__(self):

        return Foo(m = self.m, l = self.l)`

Comment: sorry, you have just replied with a different class definition. What do you want to *do* with this new class, `Foo`? Your class is also a pure python class, and this is a question specifically about Cython classes, which work differently.

Comment: I want to convert my python code to cython and I was trying to find what is the equivalent structure or method for each part in my code and I came across your answer and I was wondering to re-write my code in cython would I need to use your implementation of `copy.deepcopy` or not?

Comment: Python code is valid Cython code, so you should first try to simply use what you have (your code will be only slightly faster, obviously, but it should all *work*.) In particular, pure python classes, like `Foo`, should work exactly the same whether baked into a Cython compiled file or not. If I were you I would try your specific case, and if I got a problem *then* ask a question, with a specific example of code that crashes. (feel free to link to a new question here if you do have a problem.)

Comment: I was looking to find out how I could use build-in class function and I saw a lot of comments that `__copy__` function won't work in cython.

Comment: My advice would be to implement `__reduce__` as well as `__copy__`, and to use `cPickle` to copy your objects (i.e. `cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps(instance, -1))`, which should work for any Cython class that implements `__reduce__` and is slightly faster than `copy.deepcopy` for some use cases (particularly, in my experience, large nearly-JSON-compatible structures.)

Comment: Potentially relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33965606/default-behavior-of-copy-module-on-user-defined-classes/33978356