# Default behavior of copy module on user-defined classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, language-lawyer, python-2.x

When [`copy.copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy) or [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) is called on an instance of a user-defined class that does not have a `__copy__` or `__deepcopy__` method, what does Python guarantee will happen?  The official docs are disturbingly non-explicit on this matter.  Will the function always just return a new instance of the same class with a shallow/deep copy of the original object's `__dict__` (or whatever the equivalent is when `__slots__` are involved)?  Can the behavior differ between CPython, PyPy, etc.?  Does the behavior differ between Python 2 and 3?  (Ignore old-style classes.)  What would make one need to define explicit `__copy__`/`__deepcopy__` methods instead of using the default behavior?

References to *explicit* (better than implicit!) authoritative statements needed.

Comment: Failing that, you can read the `copy` module as it's apparently implemented in Python, not C: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/copy.py.

Comment: I'd reach for the source code for the 'canonical' definition. The other Python implementations usually just include a straight-up copy of the pure-python implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading through [the `copy` module's source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/copy.py), among other documents, I have determined the following:

- When `copy` or `deepcopy` is called on an instance of a user-defined new-style class that does not have a `__copy__` method and has not registered a callable with [`copy_reg.pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/copy_reg.html#copy_reg.pickle), the instance's [`__reduce_ex__`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce_ex__) method is called with a protocol of 2.  `object` defines a `__reduce_ex__` method that is inherited by all new-style classes that do not define their own, and so every instance has a `__reduce_ex__`.
- [`__reduce_ex__` and `__reduce__`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-extension-types) return values usable for pickling, and the `copy` module uses these to emulate unpickling, creating & returning a new object made from the state of the original object.  Moreover, when using `deepcopy`, the object's state (specifically, the third element of the tuple returned by `__reduce_ex__`/`__reduce__`) is deepcopied recursively before applying it to the new object.
- Some basic testing shows that calling `__reduce_ex__(2)` on an instance `x` of a simple user-defined class returns `(<function __newobj__>, (type(x),), x.__dict__, None, None)`.  In both Python 2 and Python 3, if the class does not have a `__setstate__` method, the `copy` module will then perform the equivalent of the following:

  ```
  callable, args, state, _, _ = x.__reduce_ex__(2)
  y = callable(*args)
  if deepcopying:
      state = deepcopy(state)
  y.__dict__.update(state)
  return y
  ```

So it appears that the default behavior of the `copy` functions on instances of user-defined classes is indeed to do the useful & simple thing and create a new object with a (possibly deep) copy of the original object's state.

Comment: This frustrates me to no end. Why is not deepcopy the default behavior of = or at least of any "copy" statement? I fail to see how it could be more common to want to shallow copy an object, or assign one. 
IMHO "=" should mean deepcopy, copy should mean deepcopy, and there should be a shallowcopy for those rare occasions